# c# Array.FindAllIndexOf which FindAll IndexOf

Tags: c#, arrays, indexof

I know c# has [`Array.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd.aspx) and [`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx).

Is there a `Array.FindAllIndexOf` which returns `int[]`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
string[] myarr = new string[] {"s", "f", "s"};

int[] v = myarr.Select((b,i) => b == "s" ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();
```

This will return 0, 2

If the value does not exist in the array then it will return a int[0].

make an extension method of it

```
public static class EM
{
    public static int[] FindAllIndexof<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, T val)
    {
        return values.Select((b,i) => object.Equals(b, val) ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
string[] myarr = new string[] {"s", "f", "s"};

int[] v = myarr.FindAllIndexof("s");
```

Comment: Shorter way - `Enumerable.Range(0, myarr.Length).Where(i => myarr[i] == "s").ToArray();`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal How might this be modified to find all indexes of floating point numbers equal (within precision) to a specified val?

Answer (score 7):

You can write something like :

```
string[] someItems = { "cat", "dog", "purple elephant", "unicorn" }; 
var selectedItems = someItems.Select((item, index) => new{
    ItemName = item,
    Position = index});
```

or

```
var Items = someItems.Select((item, index) => new{
    ItemName = item,
    Position = index}).Where(i => i.ItemName == "purple elephant");
```

**Read** : [**Get the index of a given item using LINQ**](http://geekswithblogs.net/SanjayU/archive/2009/10/15/quick-tip--get-the-index-of-a-given-using.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns all the zero-based index of the occurrence within the entire System.Array.

```
public static int[] FindAllIndex<T>(this T[] array, Predicate<T> match)
{
    return array.Select((value, index) => match(value) ? index : -1)
            .Where(index => index != -1).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post, but you can try the following,

```
string[] cars = {"Volvo", "BMW", "Volvo", "Mazda","BMW","BMW"};
var res = Enumerable.Range(0, cars.Length).Where(i => cars[i] == "BMW").ToList();
```

> returns **{1,4,5}** as a list

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. But you can write your own [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

```
public static int[] FindAllIndexOf<T>(this T[] a, Predicate<T> match)
{
   T[] subArray = Array.FindAll<T>(a, match);
   return (from T item in subArray select Array.IndexOf(a, item)).ToArray();
}
```

and then, for your array, call it.

Comment: Not right, return the first occurrence e.g. index 0, 0

Answer (score 1):

You can loop with [findIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhdxx3we.aspx) giving an index

```
string[] arr = { "abc", "asd", "def", "abc", "lmn", "wer" };
int index = -1;
do
{
    index = Array.IndexOf(arr, "abc", index + 1);
    System.Console.WriteLine(index);
} while (-1 != index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used Nikhil Agrawal's answer to create the following related method, which may be useful.

```
public static List<int> FindAllIndexOf<T>(List<T> values, List<T> matches)
    {
        // Initialize list
        List<int> index = new List<int>();

        // For each value in matches get the index and add to the list with indexes
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            // Find matches 
            index.AddRange(values.Select((b, i) => Equals(b, match) ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToList());

        }

        return index;
    }
```

Which takes a list with values and a list with values that are to be matched. It returns a list of integers with the index of the matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by creating only 2 integer variables. More power to you!

```
string[] seasons= { "Fall","Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Fall", "Winter"};

int i = 0;

int IndexOfFallInArray = 0;

int[] IndexesOfFall= new int[seasons.Length];

foreach (var item in seasons)
{
    if (item == "Fall")
        {
            IndexesOfFall[i] = IndexOfFallInArray;
            i++;
        }
        IndexOfFallInArray++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Available()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myarr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myarr[i] is null) //Your predicate here...
                yield return i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
// requirement for list
// using System.Collections.Generic;

// Assuming an array of strings
// Example array to search in
string[] array = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test5", "test1", "test0", "test3" };

// Example string to search for
string search = "test1";

List<int> AllIndexes = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int f = Array.IndexOf(array[i..], search);
    if (f == -1) { break; }
    AllIndexes.Add(f+i);
    i += f;
}
int[] AllIndexesArray = AllIndexes.ToArray();
```

Since `IndexOf` finds the first occurrence, we can use a simple `for` loop to iterate through the results and add them to a list. Directly using an array should work as well, but using a list is easier, I believe. It also depends on what you want to do with the result.

This might be more code then other solutions, but depending on what you're doing (example looping through the results), this might be the ideal solution.

Note: [Range indexing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range) (`[i..]`) exists since DotNet 5.

A function could look like this:

```cs
public static int[] FindAllIndexOf<T>(T[] array, T value)
{
    List<int> AllIndexes = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        int f = Array.IndexOf(array[i..], value);
        if (f == -1) { break; }
        AllIndexes.Add(f+i);
        i += f;
    }
    return AllIndexes.ToArray();
}
```

Or, using [Jawid Hassim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74101614/21197183) solution:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<int> FindAllIndexOf<T>(T[] array, T value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        int f = Array.IndexOf(array[i..], value);
        if (f > -1)
            yield return f+i;
        else break;
        i += f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm aware that the question is answered already, this is just another way of doing it. note that I used `ArrayList` instead of `int[]`

```
// required using directives
using System;
using System.Collections;

String      inputString = "The lazy fox couldn't jump, poor fox!";
ArrayList   locations   =  new ArrayList();      // array for found indexes
string[] lineArray = inputString.Split(' ');     // inputString to array of strings separated by spaces

int tempInt = 0;
foreach (string element in lineArray)
{
     if (element == "fox")
     {
         locations.Add(tempInt);   // tempInt will be the index of current found index and added to Arraylist for further processing 
     }
 tempInt++;
}
```