# How to get all indices of the highest number in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

For example, I have an array

```
arr[5] = {1, 5, 2, 3, 5}
```

and the highest number is obviously 5.

My question is how do I get both the indices of the highest number (which is 5).

The expected result is 1 and 4.

Comment: This is more of algorithmics. First, assume the first two are the largest two, then read the others and adjust.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you expect as a result? Do you need to find all indices of 5 in the array?

Comment: i need to find the 1 in arr[1] and 4 in arr[4]

Comment: I guess you already know how to find the maximal element. This question will help you to find all occurrences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443461/c-sharp-array-findallindexof-which-findall-indexof

Comment: @defaultlocale: Thanks for pointing to my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = new int[] { 1, 5, 2, 3, 5 };
        int max = arr.Max();
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == max)
                indexes.Add(i);
        }
int highindex = indexes.LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: You don't need a list, a simple LINQ query will return the same results

Answer (score 1):

Thats how you get all indexes of your highest number

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 5, 2, 3, 5 };

int max = numbers.Max();

var indexes = numbers.Select((c, i) => new 
                                       { 
                                          character = c, index = i 
                                       })
                     .Where(list => list.character == max)
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LINQ query to find the numbers and index that equal the maximum number :

```
var arr=new[] {1, 5, 2, 3, 5};
var max    = arr.Max();
var indexes= arr.Select( (n,idx)=>n==max?idx:-1)
                .Where(idx=>idx!=-1)
                .ToArray();
```

This will return `{1,4}`.

This query uses the [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that provides the index of the current element and returns that index if the number is equal to the maximum.

The original title was a bit confusing - how to find the two largest values. You can use a similar query to get the N largest values by selecting the value and index, *ordering* the results and taking first N items:

```
var indexes = arr.Select( (val,idx)=> (val:val,idx:idx) )
                 .OrderByDescending(p=>p.val)
                 .Take(2)
                 .Select(p=>p.idx);
```

This query uses C# 7 tuples to hold the intermediate results and give them a name

Comment: Simple and efficient solution.....