# How to check if a List<T> contains another List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any elegant way in `c#` to check whether a `List<T>` contains a sub-`List<T>` similar to `string.Contains(string)`?

Let's say e.g. I want to test for example whether List `A` is contained in List `B`

```
List<int> A = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> B = new List<int>{ 3, 4, 5 };
```

**important is that all elements have to match in exactly that order.**

---

I know I could possibly do something like

```
bool Contains(List<Sampletype> source, List<Sampletype> sample)
{
    // sample has to be smaller or equal length
    if (sample.Count > source.Count) return false;

    // doesn't even contain first element
    if (!source.Contains(sample[0])) return false;

    // get possible starts
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10443540/7111561
    int[] possibleStartIndexes = source.Select((b, i) => b == sample[0] ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();

    foreach (int possibleStartIndex in possibleStartIndexes)
    {
        // start is too late -> can't match
        if (possibleStartIndex + sample.Count - 1 > source.Count - 1) return false;

        for (int index = possibleStartIndex; index < possibleStartIndex + sample.Count; index++)
        {
            // if one element does not match the whole sample doesn't match
            if (source[index] != sample[index]) return false;
        }

        // if this is reached all elements of the sample matched
        Debug.Log("Match found starting at index " + possibleStartIndex);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But I hope there is a better way to do so.

Comment: So, this is effectively a "substring" search. Sounds like, rather than reinventing the wheel, you should attempt to implement [K-M-P algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

Comment: You could use Enumerable.Intersect then count the result ? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: we could build a wrapper around these classes and give them unique IDs. Class AList{List<int> my_345List{get;set; }

Comment: @spender while the duplicate solves what I'm doing in a better and beautiful way as far as I understand it you are right and implementing that algorithm would be more efficient since it avoids the looping over all elements, thanks for the input, I'll try that as well!

Comment: @aspxsushil sorry I don't see at which point this would help?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a oneliner:

```
var result = A.Select(a => $"{a}").Aggregate((c, n) => $"{c};{n}").Contains(B.Select(b => $"{b}").Aggregate((c, n) => $"{c};{n}"));
```

It basically creates a string from each list, and checks whether the A string contains the B string. This way you won't just get a method *like* `string.Contains`, you actually get to use just that.

**EDIT**
Added separator to the string aggregations, as {1, 2, 3} would result in the same string as {1, 23}

**EDIT 2**
Re-adding my first approach which identifies if list B is present in list A, perhaps scattered, but still ordered:

```
var result = B.Intersect(A).SequenceEqual(B)
```

Comment: You don't need `ToList()`, `SequenceEqual()` works on `IEnumerable` which is returned by `Intersect`

Comment: An `Intersect` of { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 5 } and { 3, 4, 5 } would produce { 3, 4, 5 }. This would not produce the correct evaluation.

Comment: @Adrian: My bad, I'll remove ToList().

Comment: Furthemore, I found that I intersected in the wrong order, fixing that too

Comment: @Eliasar, ah, sorry, I missed that they were not allowed to be scattered.

Comment: @KristofferLerbækPedersen according to the example of { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 5 }, there is no sequence of { 3, 4, 5}. `Intersect` would produce that result, giving a false positive

Comment: Edited it with a oneliner that should do the trick. Not as pretty, though.

Comment: If you create an extension method, you can name it something like `ContainsSequence`

Comment: @KristofferLerbækPedersen thanks for your efforts! The duplicate link solves this in a better way. **However** though Eliasar is right and the example didn't show it I might be also interested in finding scattered patterns (I actually didn't exclude the possibility - just said the order is important) so I'ld like to upvoted your answer for the previous version using `B.Intersect(A).SequenceEqual(B);`

Comment: Actually you did exclude the scattered pattern in your question, as you asked for functionality similar to `string.Contains(string)`, which was the part I missed.I agree that the duplicate link is more elegant, and it's what I'd go with as well, I just thought I'd leave my alternative approach here. I'll re-add my first answer and clarify that it's for a scattered pattern, and I'm glad you found use for it.

Comment: @KristofferLerbækPedersen hehe yeah actually I didn't think about the scattered version until you poeple mentioned it here .. than I thought like "hmm actually very usefull as well" ^^

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want to slide over `A` and check each element of that window with the `B`. The last part is actually `SequenceEqual` and I do recommend to use it but this is just an alternative to explain the point:

```
bool equal = Enumerable.Range(0, A.Count() - B.Count() + 1)
    .Select(i => A.Skip(i).Take(B.Count))
    .Any(w => w.Select((item, i) => item.Equals(B[i])).All(item => item));
```

Comment: This doesn't check for order