# Remove non matching number from two arrays

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `foreach` that loops over two `arrays` to check if the numbers are matching and in the same order as each other.

However one of the `arrays` can have some extra numbers that I want to remove/ignore before comparing.

Example:

```
int[] currentTracingPoints = new int[] { 1,2,3,4 };
int[] part = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

I would like to remove the number 4 from `currentTracingPoints`

Example:

```
int[] currentTracingPoints = new int[] {4,5,6,8};
int[] part = new int[] {4,5,8};
```

I would like to remove the number 6 from `currentTracingPoints`

I am using Unity

```cs
foreach (TracingPart part in tracingParts) { // check tracing parts
    if (currentTracingPoints.Count == part.order.Length && !part.succeded) {
        // check whether the previous tracing parts are succeeded
        if (PreviousLettersPartsSucceeded (part, tracingParts)) {
            equivfound = true; // assume true
            for (int i = 0; i < currentTracingPoints.Count; i++) {
                int index = (int) currentTracingPoints [i];
                if (index != part.order [i]) {
                    equivfound = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and what is your question? What is not working right?

Comment: In both cases the result you want in `currentTracingPoints` seems to be just `part`. Why not just use `part`? What am I missing?

Comment: currently the code works if both `arrays` are exactly the same values in the same order `{1,2,3}` . However sometimes `currentTracingPoints` will have have extra numbers that I want to remove first before I compare check to see if both `arrays` have the same order of numbers.

Comment: The two `arrays` that I compare are `currentTracingPoints` and `part`. Everything else are just Unity parent `Objects`

Comment: Really you could ignore the the `foreach` code. i just put it there as context for what I am doing. Really I just want to look at two `arrays` and remove the extra values form `currentTracingPoints`. Then I can do my compare checking after

Comment: If you want to dynamically remove elements you would be better using `List` .. and then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54677133/7111561) which provides a **match between lists that can be scattered** `var result = B.Intersect(A).SequenceEqual(B)`

Comment: and what if arrays have same values but in different order, say currentTracingPoints ={1,2,3} and part = {1,3,2}. what would be the desired resultant array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in removing the elements with your own code.
I would use lists for each array because they would be more malleable.

You would iterate over currentTracingPoints backwards, and remove any that can't be found in the part array.

```
List< int > currentTracingPoints = new List<int> ( { 1, 2, 3, 4 } );
List< int > parts = new List<int> ( { 1, 2, 3 } );

for ( int index = currentTracingPoints.Count-1; index >= 0; index-- )
{
    if ( !parts.Contains( currentTracingPoints[ index ] ) )
    {
        currentTracingPoints.RemoveAt( index );
    }
}
```

And then you will be left an array that matches parts.
Then you can convert the list to an int array with [ToArray](https://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-array)

I'm not 100% sure if this absolutely the fastest, but it would work. Wether or not it becomes a performance bottleneck would depend on the size of the arrays and other nessary processes surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the difference between the two arrays by using LINQ:

```
int[] diff = currentTracingPoints.Except(part);
```

And then when iterating in your loop, you can see if the current *part* exists in the diff array, and if it does just skip the current iteration.

Hopefully I am understanding what you need correctly, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8), using Linq:

```
var result = currentTracingPoints.Intersect(part);
```

This one compares and remove the elements that are not in both arrays.

It's the equivalent of the [mathematical intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection).

---

```
int[] currentTracingPoints = new int[] { 1,2,3,4 };
int[] part = new int[] {1,2,3};

currentTracingPoints.Intersect(part);

foreach(var x in currentTracingPoints.Intersect(part))
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: I get an error `ArrayList` does not contain  definition for "intersect" for `var result = currentTracingPoints.Intersect(part);`

Comment: Add `using System.Linq`