# In PowerShell is there a way to return the index of an array with substring of a string

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, indices

Is there another way return the indices of every instance of a substring in an array besides old fashioned looping through indices?

```
$myarray = @('herp','dederp','dedoo','flerp')
$substring = 'erp'
$indices = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $myarray.length; $i++) {
    if ($myarray[$i] -match $substring){
       $indices = $indices + $i
   }
}


$thisiswrong = @($myarray.IndexOf($substring))
```

The conditional inside that kind of for loop is kinda cumbersome, and `$thisiswrong` only ever gets a value of [-1]

Comment: yep it was a copy paste error $flarray is the real variable in my script, $myarray is what I used to ask a question, sorry about that.
Thanks mklement0

Comment: In this [Automatic variable for the pipeline index `#13772`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13772) idea, it would be something like: `$indices = $myarray | Foreach-Object { if ($_ -match $substring) { $PSIndex } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **use LINQ** (adapted from [this C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59580449/45375)):

```
$myarray = 'herp', 'dederp', 'dedoo', 'flerp'
$substring = 'erp'

[int[]] $indices = [Linq.Enumerable]::Range(0, $myarray.Count).
                     Where({ param($i) $myarray[$i] -match $substring })
```

`$indices` receives `0, 1, 3`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$thisiswrong = @($myarray.IndexOf($substring))`

[`System.Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array.IndexOf) only ever finds *one* index and matches *entire* elements, literally and case-sensitively in the case of strings.

---

There's a **more PowerShell-like, but much slower alternative**, as hinted at by [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65031344/45375); you can take advantage of the fact that the match-information objects that [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) outputs have a `.LineNumber` property, reflecting the `1`-based index of the position in the input collection - even if the input doesn't come from a file:

```
$myarray = 'herp', 'dederp', 'dedoo', 'flerp'
$substring = 'erp'

[int[]] $indices = 
  ($myarray | Select-String $substring).ForEach({ $_.LineNumber - 1 })
```

Note the need to subtract `1` from each `.LineNumber` value to get the `0`-based *array* indices, and the use of the [`.ForEach()` array *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach), which performs better than the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a file...

```
get-content file | select-string erp | select line, linenumber

Line   LineNumber
----   ----------
herp            1
dederp          2
flerp           4
```

Comment: Nice, but worth mentioning explicitly that line numbers are `1`-, not `0`-based. If that isn't a concern, you don't even need a _file_: `'herp','dederp','dedoo','flerp' | select-string erp | select line, linenumber`